# How can I open a specific modal in a specific page with url in react?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-router

I use "react-router-modal" and it works well. When I click the link the modal will appear correctly with its new path in browser's address bar.

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <section>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <ModalLink path='/foo' component={FooModal}>
                            Say Hello
                        </ModalLink>
                        <ModalContainer/>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

class FooModal extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>Foo modal says hi!</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I added this linen in routes.js file too.

```
<ModalRoute path="/foo" parentPath="/" component={FooModal}/>
```

But I need it viceversa. 
It means When I enter the path show the page with this modal open but only a blank page will be shown.